# Oracle DB active/passive setup with Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, loopbackjs, node-oracledb

I want to understand how the Oracle db active passive connection works with Node js. Currently my project is using loopback Oracle connector node module. What configuration I have to do in db or app or env level to complete the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you connect through a connection pool you don’t need to do anything since the connection pool should take care of failed connections, as long as one succeeds.

This ofcourse assumes a correct sqlnet configuration in the connection pool, that by itself should be prefixed by a vip.

Comment: Some of the node-oracledb doc on [high available](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionha) may help.  Most (all?) of this can be set and used with Loopback.

Comment: I used connectString and passed DESCRIPTION_LIST, it is throwing "Error: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist".
const connectString =`(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(FAILOVER=ON)(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${process.env.DB_HOST_1})(PORT=${process.env.DB_PORT_1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${process.env.DB_NAME_1})))(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=${process.env.DB_HOST_2})(PORT=${process.env.DB_PORT_2})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${process.env.DB_NAME_2}))))`;

Comment: It looks like host is not resolved to something useful.

Comment: what did you change? (I assume the HOST parameter)